# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine 2 one-to-many checkbox hydration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I have a `ManyToMany` that I broke into `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationship. I want to build a form that has checkboxes instead of collection, and I am using the 'DoctrineObject' hydrator, but it does not work and I don't know what is going wrong.

I removed from my code below all of the other not related fields.

**Role Entity**:

```
/**
 * @orm\Entity
 * @orm\Table(name="roles")
 */
class RolesEntity extends HemisEntity {
    /**
     * @orm\Id
     * @orm\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    
    /**
     * @orm\Column(name="role_code",type="string")
     */
    protected $roleCode;

    /**
     * @orm\OneToMany(targetEntity="RolesPermissionsEntity", mappedBy="role", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $rolePermissions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rolePermissions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setRolePermissions($rolePermissions)
    {
        $this->rolePermissions = $rolePermissions;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function addRolePermissions(Collection $rolePermissions)
    {
        foreach ($rolePermissions as $rolePermission) {
            $rolePermission->setRole($this);
            $this->rolePermissions->add($rolePermission);
        }
    }
    
    public function removeRolePermissions(Collection $rolePermissions)
    {
        foreach ($rolePermissions as $rolePermission) {
            $rolePermission->setRole(null);
            $this->rolePermissions->removeElement($rolePermission);
        }
    }
    
    public function getRolePermissions()
    {
        return $this->rolePermissions;
    }
}
```

**The ManyToMany table entity** (*it has more fields and so I broke it*):

```
    /**
 * @orm\Entity
 * @orm\Table(name="roles_permissions")
 */
class RolesPermissionsEntity extends HemisEntity {
    /**
     * @orm\Id
     * @orm\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    
    /**
     * @orm\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RolesEntity", inversedBy="rolePermissions")
     * @orm\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $role;
    
    /**
     * @orm\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PermissionsEntity", inversedBy="permissionRoles")
     * @orm\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $permission;
    
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function setPermission($permission)
    {
        $this->permission = $permission;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPermission()
    {
        return $this->permission;
    }
}
```

**My form look like this**:

```
class RoleForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('role');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new RolesEntity());

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            'name' => 'id'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name'    => 'roleCode',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Role Code'
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'rolePermissions',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Permissions',
                'object_manager' => $objectManager,
                'target_class'   => 'Hemis\Fnd\PermissionsEntity',
                'property'       => 'permissionDesc'
            ),
        ));
        
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type'  => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'roleCode' => array(
                'required' => false
            ),
            'rolePermissions' => array(
                'required' => true
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I dump the `$role` it does not contain any `rolePermissions` and even though they are passed from the form they are just not hydrated into the object.

What is wrong with my code? Is there a better way to do that using checkboxes?

Comment: i don't understand, why did you break the many-to-many relationship? plus, where is the PermissionsEntity ? you're entity graph seems a bit off.

try just having a RolesEntity m2m with PermissionsEntity.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RoleForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        // ...

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'rolePermissions',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Role Permissions',
                'count' => 0,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'target_element' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Fieldset',
                    'options' => array(
                        'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
                    ),
                    'elements' => array(
                        // add form fields for the properties of the RolesPermissionsEntity class here
                        array(
                            'name' => 'id',
                            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'role',
                            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
                            // other options
                        ),
                        // ...
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're incorrectly handling rolePermissions. when using the DoctrineHydrator, you need to make sure that the field is property configured to handle the association with RolesPermissionsEntity

```
class RoleForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('role');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new RolesEntity());

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            'name' => 'id'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name'    => 'roleCode',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Role Code'
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'rolePermissions',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Permissions',
                'object_manager' => $objectManager,
                'target_class'   => 'Hemis\Fnd\RolesPermissionsEntity', // Update the target class to RolesPermissionsEntity
                'property'       => 'permission', // Update the property to permission
                'is_method'      => true, // Add this line
                'find_method'    => array( // Add this line
                    'name'   => 'findPermissionsForRole', // Replace with your custom method name
                    'params' => array(
                        'criteria' => array('role' => $this->getObject()), // Use the getObject() method to get the current RolesEntity object
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type'  => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'roleCode' => array(
                'required' => false
            ),
            'rolePermissions' => array(
                'required' => true
            )
        );
    }
}
```